# A search for columnstore index yields no results

Tags: bug, search

A search for [*columnstore index*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=columnstore%20index&submit=search) yields no results.

However, the first suggestion returned by the search engine is to instead search for *[columnstore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=columnstore)*. That search clearly shows several hits that contain the phrase "columnstore index". Searching for ["columnstore index"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22columnstore%20index%22) (in quotes) returns two of them; naturally, it misses "columnstore indexes".

[image: Search results for columnstore index.]

Why are these hits missed by the first search query?

Answer (score 3):

It's converting the `index` word to a tag search automatically since it's one of the top tags.

[image]

The questions that contain `columnstore` don't have the `index` tag.  I added that tag to my question about `columnstore`, but we may need to set up synonyms for the tags to help in searches.

The quotes eliminate the auto-conversion to an `index` tag search.  You can get the same results by searching for `columnstore "index"`.